# Binding API data with drop down in react native

Tags: react-native

I am building a sample application in react native in which i need to display data of API using for loop in drop down. It is displaying data in console.log() but with error and also not showing it no mobile phone .

**Below are the code files**

```
  for(i=0; i<=this.state.droparray.length;i++)
              {
              var str_Code=this.state.droparray[i].Code
              console.log('Code agya h+++++++ ', str_Code)
              
              }

   <DropDownPicker
                                items={[
                                    { label: 'ABC-12345678901',Code: 'PP-12345678901', },
                                    { label: 'ABC-12345678902',Code: 'PP-12345678902', },
                                    { label: 'ABC-12345678903',Code: 'PP-12345678903', },
                                    { label: 'ABC-12345678904',Code: 'PP-12345678904', },
                                    { label: 'ABC-12345678905',Code: 'PP-12345678905', },
                                    

                                ]}

                                // defaultValue={this.state.item}
                                containerStyle={{ height: '20%'}}
                                placeholder="Select A Numbers"
                                style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                                itemStyle={{
                                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',



                                }}

                                dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                                onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
                                    Code: item.Code
                                })}

                
                />
                  </View>
```

**Any solution please ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below

```
state = {
   droparray: [];
}

async componentDidMount() {
   try {
       const droparray = await fetch('https://example.com/'); 
       // example like [{name: "John"},{name: "William"}];

       var res = [];
       droparray.map((item) {
          res.push({...item, label: item.name}); 
          // this process is for DropDownPicker as required label in data
      });

            
      this.setState({droparray: res});
   } catch(err) {
      console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
   }
} 
  

<View> 
  <DropDownPicker
    items={this.state.droparray} // Do something like so it will reflect on view
    .......          
  />
</View>
```